# how to show a div with visibility hidden when using scrapy

Tags: css, scrapy

I'm using scrapy to crawl a page and don't know how to get the content of a div with visibility hidden.

I used xpath response.xpath('//div[@class='abc']').extract() but got an empty list.

What can I do to solve this problem?

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this:

```
response.xpath('//div[@class='abc']').extract()
```

use this:

```
response.xpath("//div[@class='abc']").extract()
```

Remark the double quotes.

Comment: Or: `response.xpath('//div[@class="abc"]').extract()` depending on your preference ;)